# How can I make Sorbet see an ignored class?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have just installed Sidekiq into my Rails project. Unfortunately, Sorbet doesn't like it. For some reason it thinks that `Sidekiq::Job` is a class instead of a module and so it keeps throwing the following error:

[image]

Either the RBI files for Sidekiq are out of date or something else is amiss. Unfortunately it's almost impossible for me to update RBI files right now because doing so generates literally thousands of errors elsewhere which I do not have the bandwidth to fix.

So my approach to solving this was to changed `#typed: false` to `# typed: ignore`. This does solve the errors in the tracking file...

[image]

However as soon as I do that, any upstream files that reference this `Tracking` class start complaining that it doesn't exist (even when the upstream file has `# typed: false`:

[image]

This feels like being in the most frustrating Catch 22. I can't currently figure out how to install Sidekiq without either trying to upgrade all of the sorbet installation or alternatively switching sorbet off entirely.

#### How can I make Sorbet see an ignored class?

How can I make sure that Sorbet can see my class even when `typed` is set to `ignore`?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a suggestion :)

My guess is that you're trying to use `sorbet-typed` with the latest Sidekiq. There was a relatively recent [change](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/f1b24da9c225a5512120514d32a5348760e92f3a#diff-25f829140be25a886134933b537d356dddb12234ca85319e50b381f9edb6b74dL303) in Sidekiq (so now [Job is a module](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/ad9442f116086424948d60ec059755f9168a6bc8/lib/sidekiq/job.rb#L44)) that [is not reflected](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet-typed/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/all/sidekiq.rbi#L175) yet in the sorbet-typed definitions...

I'd say there are 2 options:

1. (better) Update sorbet-typed to reflect the recent Sidekiq changes
2. Use older Sidekiq

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. In desperation I eventually went the Tapioca route which was actually more straightforward than I expected. Though still not there yet - and not clear if I've actually fixed the Sidekiq issue either so... fingers crossed